# Adding extra label on upper axis X

Tags: tikz-pgf, charts

lets consider following source code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
        ,xmin=0,xmax=3
        ,ymin=0,ymax=15
        ,extra x ticks={2.2}
        ,extra x tick style={%
            ,grid=major
            ,ticklabel pos=top
            }
        ,extra x tick labels={Cut}
        ]
        \addplot {exp(x)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It leads to:
[image]

However, I would like to add upper label of upper axis X, I am going to have two labels - down and up (I can add down axis X label)., something like:
[image]

Could someone help me, please?

Answer (score 1):

The style of a x label can be added with :

```
x label style={}
```

In there, you can give the known `at` from tikz like

```
at={(axis description cs:x,y)}
```

where `x` and `y` are referred to the total fraction of the width and the height of your axes.

Full code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
    x label style={at={(axis description cs:0.5,1.1)},anchor=north},
         xlabel={\color{red}Upper Axis},
        ,xmin=0,xmax=3
        ,ymin=0,ymax=15
        ,extra x ticks={2.2}
        ,extra x tick style={%
            ,grid=major
            ,ticklabel pos=top
            }
        ,extra x tick labels={Cut}
        ]
        \addplot {exp(x)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which gives:

[image]

Alternative, you could use `axis cs:x,y`

where `x` and `y` are riffered to the axes values:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
    x label style={at={(axis cs:1.5,17)},anchor=north},
         xlabel={\color{red}Upper Axis},
        ,xmin=0,xmax=3
        ,ymin=0,ymax=15
        ,extra x ticks={2.2}
        ,extra x tick style={%
            ,grid=major
            ,ticklabel pos=top
            }
        ,extra x tick labels={Cut}
        ]
        \addplot {exp(x)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:** For a second `xlabel` if you don't need a `ylabel` as in your MWE above, you may use a rotated `ylabel` as in the code below (other solutions also can be found but this was my first thought right now):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
    x label style={at={(axis description cs:0.5,-0.1)},anchor=north},
    xlabel={\color{magenta} Bottom Axis},
    y label style={at={(axis description cs: 0.5,1.1)},anchor=center,rotate=-90},
    ylabel={\color{red}Upper Axis},
        ,xmin=0,xmax=3
        ,ymin=0,ymax=15
        ,extra x ticks={2.2}
        ,extra x tick style={%
            ,grid=major
            ,ticklabel pos=top
            }
        ,extra x tick labels={Cut}
        ]
        \addplot {exp(x)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Another solution is to follow [Manual](http://ginkgo.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/www/BachoTeX2009/LORCH/MiKTeX%202.7/doc/latex/pgfplots/pgfplots.pdf) for Package
pgfplots version 1.1,  at page 45 to add an extra label:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{document}% THE NAXT CODE is from the manual and adds an extra label:
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
extra description/.code={
\node at (0.5,-0.1) {\color{magenta}Lower Axis};
}}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
    x label style={at={(axis cs:1.5,17)},anchor=north},
         xlabel={\color{red}Upper Axis},
        ,xmin=0,xmax=3
        ,ymin=0,ymax=15
        ,extra x ticks={2.2}
        ,extra x tick style={%
            ,grid=major
            ,ticklabel pos=top
            }
        ,extra x tick labels={Cut}
        ]
        \addplot {exp(x)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please note that I wrote about two labels - bottom and up·

Comment: @Developer, I added a way, but using `ylabel` that you might need also... And a second solution by adding an extra label.

Comment: Maybe, is it possible to use second ylabel as second xlabel? (I need one ylabel - only one).

Comment: Did you checked both ways I added? I think you can do what you want in any case... Please test the two ways and just chose one or pleas edit your question because I can't understand the problem...

Comment: @Developer... I mean that I think my code does exactly what you mean. If you call it a x label or a y label is a matter of the name of the command.... Upper and Lower labels does not exist by default and I just used these commands to create them

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to TeX.SE! Very similar to koleygr's answer except that I use a different anchor, which may be advantageous for placing the text irrespectively of the font size, and refrain from using `\color` since it is arguably better to add the color information to the style.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
        x label style={at={(axis description cs:0.3,1.0)},anchor=south,
        text=purple},
         xlabel={upper axis $x$ label},
        ,xmin=0,xmax=3
        ,ymin=0,ymax=15
        ,extra x ticks={2.2}
        ,extra x tick style={%
            ,grid=major
            ,ticklabel pos=top
            }
        ,extra x tick labels={Cut}
        ]
        \addplot {exp(x)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]